# UITapGestureRecognizer Crashes App..?

Tags: swift, swift3, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using image views to display users' friends lists. The user should be able to tap on a friend's icon and be taken to another screen. The code I've written works perfectly on the Xcode simulator. However, when running on a device, the app crashes every single time as soon as I tap an icon.

I really am unsure where to even start debugging this, even after tons of google-ing. Any advice/ help is appreciated.

I have read that my specific error potentially has something to do with memory allocation(?) but still unsure where to start/ what to do. When I check my device logs, the exception type shows this: **Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)**. I've followed tutorials on finding zombies and it did not help. Thank you.

I'm not really sure what code to post, but since you'll probably want to make sure I am setting up the icons correctly: (i've deleted some code to keep it simple as possible; this is running in a loop to create x amount of icons)

```
let iv = UIImageView()
iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
iv.image = image!
iv.tag = j
iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.iconTapped))
iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
iv.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

iconTapped function:

```
func iconTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer, _ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("TAPPED NUMBER: \(gestureRecognizer.view?.tag)")

    tappedIcon = CurrentSixFriendsList[(gestureRecognizer.view?.tag)!]

    let nextVC = ConfirmOpponentViewController()
    nextVC.chosenOpponent = tappedIcon
    navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I've commented out all code on nextVC and all code in iconTapped except for a print statement. The app still crashes on device only when I tap any friend icon.

```
  func iconTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer, _ sender: AnyObject) {

    print("tapped")

}
```

**SECOND UPDATE:**
so i commented out all the code for rendering the image views and I hardcoded an image view. (just one image view) with a static image from my project. the image view displays and the app crashes even when i tap on this imageView. why is it acting so strange!? i'm going crazy...
I added this code in VDL just to experiment:

```
 let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "settings icon")
    view.addSubview(iv)
    iv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    iv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    iv.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    iv.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(iconTapped))
    iv.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: Try to avoiding `!` and be happy...

Comment: I avoided it on the update but I am still very unhappy.. :(

Comment: Is a tableview / collectionview involved when you say you have a list of images? Or are you just creating the images in a loop with the tapgesturerecognizers and putting them somewhere in a static manner?

Comment: @aksh1t no collection view or table view. Just a loop that creates x amount of image views and adds them to the screen as icons with images. I've set userEnabled to true so they can be tapped. I restrict the amount of icons allowed on the screen - in a static manner, yes

Comment: The weird part is that your code does run on the simulator, but not in the actual device. The only thing that I can think of is to ask you to double check the UIImage name strings (the simulator is not case sensitive, the device is). Also, double check that you have the retina and 3x images if you are using them in the appropriate device.

Comment: @aksh1t the images are being retrieved from my api. they display properly. i just tried an experiment, check my newest update above. it HAS to be the image view somehow

Comment: Can you try changing the name of the method for the tapGestureRecognizer? I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982581/uitapgesturerecognizer-crashes-on-multiple-taps) and it does not explain why, but somehow renaming the method fixed the crash for that person.

Comment: @aksh1t no luck. I changed it to iconWasTapped cleaned and rebuilt the project and still crashes. :(

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a very simple project that showcases this crash and put it up on github or somewhere? I can probably poke and prod and try to see what's wrong. Without any more context, I'm sorry but can't think of anything else.

Comment: @aksh1t may not be ideal, but i've just copied pasted the code into 2 files at the following link. there really isnt much code so i did this way... but this is also making the device crash (not simulator)..just use any image you have local: https://github.com/cdowney102/crash

Comment: I was able to repro the crash on my device. I'll try to look into it and let you know if I find something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, found out why it was crashing.

Your tapped function:

```
func iconTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer, _ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("tapped")
}
```

should be like this:

```
func iconTapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // To get the sender's tag, do this:
    print(gesture.view.tag)
}
```

Also adjust the #selector to the right function.

When setting a selector to `UITapGestureRecognizer`, the recognizer object will call the selector with only the sender, and you can not add another argument to that function.

So, the root cause of the crash is because you are trying to fit a method with one argument (which is what the gesture sends out) into a method with two arguments. This crash was very interesting because it worked all right on the simulator but only crashed in an actual device. I guess it was because the simulator and the device handle functions with extra parameters differently? (simulator ignores it vs. device crashes). If you find anything deeper as to why exactly this was happening, I would love to know.

Comment: IT WORKED! the weird thing is that I was looking at the parameters this morning thinking it is weird they don't match...but when I search stack, other people had been using these exact params and were not complaining of a crash. THANK YOU!

Comment: You just saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

Most probly your CurrentSixFriendsList doesnot have value of gestureRecognizer.view?.tag)!.But a breakpoint before this line

```
tappedIcon = CurrentSixFriendsList[(gestureRecognizer.view?.tag)!]
```

Even then if you dont get an error then install crashlytics.This is a tool which will tell your crash issue.

Comment: so i've added the following print statement and added the suggested breakpoint. tapped icon is not empty at time of crash. print("TAPPED FRIEND INFO: \(CurrentSixFriendsList[(gestureRecognizer.view?.tag)!])")

Comment: comment all the code in viewController life cycle functions in nextVC and then run....

Comment: so i have commented all functions on the nextVC, and I also commented out everything under the tapped icon function. the only thing that iconTapped function does now is print("tapped") and it is still crashing on tap...it has to be something with the image view or gesture recognizer right?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your tap gesture code & From swift 3.x you need to use #selector

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


@objc func dismissKeyboard(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```